# Will JSF binding cause memory leak and causing thousands of UI components in HTTP Session

Tags: jsf, memory-leaks, binding

We found that the system is frequently running out of memory, running Full GC did not help to reclaim the memory. We then take a heap dump an analyse the contents.

JSF implementation name/version Mojarra 2.1.28-jbossorg-2
Server name/version : JBoss EAP 6.3

We found some HTTP sessions are holding more than 2GB of memory. A screen dump of the dominator_tree from the MAT is attached in the following link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zX1xHzpXBacrDuSNrS2Dp1kVUDm00uku/view?usp=sharing

It shows that there are many `org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView` components (about 360 of them) , each referring to 5M to 9M of memory and refers to a particular set of UI in the system !

I raised a question in the primefaces forum and it is suggested that the problem may be related to JSF bindings.

I checked with the source of the page and it contains:

```
    <f:actionListener binding="#{CourseInfoManagedBean.initBatchUpload()}"/>
```

where CourseInfoManagedBean is a `@ViewScoped` bean.

Will that cause memory leak ?

Moreover, why those `org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView` UI components are created directly under the `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession` rather than under the `com.sun.faces.util.LRUMap` ?

Comment: Why do you use an `f:actionListener` with a binding? What is the usecase?

Comment: Do you possibly instantiate TabViews dynamicalle from within a bean and store them in view or session scope?

Comment: And please try an [mcve] in a more recent JSF version

Comment: In short btw, the answer to the 'leak' is sort of yes. The answer to the second question is either caused by something that is wrong in the existing code or a possible bug in jsf which might be solved in newer versions of mojarra or a lack of it in myfaces (like also mentioned in the primefaces forum and adding a link to this btw in your question is good practice)

Comment: Binding a component to bean property will do that yes. The abovelinked duplicate clearly explains that. The `<f:actionListener binding>` does however not bind a component to a bean property. It only binds a bean action method to the parent component. So you need to search further for the real cause.

Comment: Reply to Selaron,  no, we do not instantiate TabViews dynamically and thus it is strange to find out them stored in the HTTP session directly.

Comment: In general But looking them up in a method, assigning them to a field that is in the session is also causing them to be stored. Every holding of a reference does